# Passar valor de variável dentro de texto com echo

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando adicionar um valor a uma variável dentro de um texto com `echo` e não estou conseguindo, o valor está disponível pois consigo acessa-lo.

O que tenho é isso, não consegui inserir o código de forma adequada, por isso a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observando pelo console do `Chrome` tenho isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado do print_r($_SESSION):

```
Array ( [usuarioID] => 124 [nomeUsuario] => Valter Ferreira Martins [email] => webdevelopermgri@gmail.com [IdCategoria] => 0 [Cliente] => 4 [produtos_1417] => 13 [produtos_1676] => 0 [produtos_1207] => 0 [produtos_1306] => 1 [produtos_1508] => 1 )
```

Quando posiciono o ponteiro do mouse sobre o botão Adicionar a variável está sem valor, mas no console o valor está disponível.

Comment: Coloca aí o código fonte usa o botao `{ }` para exibir ele corretamente. Da um `print_r($_SESSION);` tbm

Comment: No `href` tem aspas duplas sobrando, remova uma delas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O link na imagem parece montado errado, tem uma aspa dupla sobrando, remova ela

Mude:

```
<a href="produtos.php?Cliente="'.$_SESSION['Cliente'] .'" class="btn ....
aspa a mais ------------------^
```

Para:

```
<a href="produtos.php?Cliente='.$_SESSION['Cliente'] .'" class="btn ....
```

Comment: Obrigado @rray, resolveu o problema, não estava conseguindo ver essas aspas sobrando.

Answer (score 1):

Para usar echo em php voce precisa usar aspas duplas ou concatenar, o codigo php sempre fica dentro de `<?php ... ?>` no html.

```
<?php
   $variavel = 123;

   //aspas duplas permite usar variaveis sem concatenar
   echo "<p>o numero é $variavel</p>";

   // ou 
   echo '<p>o numero é '.$variavel.'</p>';

?>
```

Comment: Obrigado @Ivo Ribeiro, ajudou muito.

Answer (score 1):

Variáveis só podem receber o valor dentro de aspas duplas. Aspas simples é para literais em PHP.

Certo:

```
echo "$minhaVariavel";
```

Errado:

```
echo '$minhaVariavel';
```

Comment: obrigado pela dica.